# Jquery modal is holding the previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery modal to show some table data dynamically ,now the problem is that on each iteration the data which is created is appended into the modal but next time it is holding the previous  row ,How to get rid of that i am posting my code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="event-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header-avaliability">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Avilable Interviews</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="myTable">
              <tr>
               <th width="10%">Company Name</th>
               <th width="10%">Interviewer</th>
               <th width="10%">Subject</th>
               <th width="10%">Timing</th>
               <th width="10%">Consultant Name </th>
               <th width="10%">Candidate Name </th>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

javascript operation

```
jQuery.getJSON(url+"&date=" +date.format()+"&consultantID="+consultantID+"&teamName="+teamName+"&type="+type, function(data)  {

        var $formrow =0 ;
        var arr =0;
        var arr1 =0;
        var arr2 =0 ;
        var arr3 = 0;
             for(var z=0; z<data.applicationArray.length;z++){
                applicationArray = data.applicationArray[z].split("##%%$$");                

                 arr = applicationArray.slice();
                 arr1 = arr[0].slice();
                 arr2 = arr[1].slice();
                 arr3 = arr[2].slice();
                 arr4 = arr[3].slice();
                 arr5 = arr[4].slice();
                 arr6 = arr[5].slice();

                $formrow = '<tr><td>'+arr1+'</td><td>'+arr2+'</td><td>'+arr3+'</td><td>'+arr4+'</td><td>'+arr5+'</td><td>'+arr6+'</td></tr>';
                $('.myTable').append($formrow);
                }
             $('#event-modal').modal('show');

            });
```

the modal is holding the previous value ,i am using $('#event-modal').html('') but not working somebody please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery.getJSON(url+"&date=" +date.format()+"&consultantID="+consultantID+"&teamName="+teamName+"&type="+type, function(data)  {

        var $formrow =0 ;
        var arr =0;
        var arr1 =0;
        var arr2 =0 ;
        var arr3 = 0;
            $(".myTable").html('<tr> <th width="10%">Company Name</th> <th width="10%">Interviewer</th> <th width="10%">Subject</th> <th width="10%">Timing</th> <th width="10%">Consultant Name </th> <th width="10%">Candidate Name </th> </tr>');
             for(var z=0; z<data.applicationArray.length;z++){
                applicationArray = data.applicationArray[z].split("##%%$$");                

                 arr = applicationArray.slice();
                 arr1 = arr[0].slice();
                 arr2 = arr[1].slice();
                 arr3 = arr[2].slice();
                 arr4 = arr[3].slice();
                 arr5 = arr[4].slice();
                 arr6 = arr[5].slice();

                $formrow = '<tr><td>'+arr1+'</td><td>'+arr2+'</td><td>'+arr3+'</td><td>'+arr4+'</td><td>'+arr5+'</td><td>'+arr6+'</td></tr>';
                $('.myTable').append($formrow);
                }
             $('#event-modal').modal('show');

            });
```

This will work. add `$(".myTable").html('<tr> <th width="10%">Company Name</th> <th width="10%">Interviewer</th> <th width="10%">Subject</th> <th width="10%">Timing</th> <th width="10%">Consultant Name </th> <th width="10%">Candidate Name </th> </tr>');` So that the `.myTable` refresh everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Just empty your `.myTable` before appending anything in `for loop` as below:

```
jQuery.getJSON(url+"&date=" +date.format()+"&consultantID="+consultantID+"&teamName="+teamName+"&type="+type, function(data)  
{
    $('.myTable').empty();
    //rest of code..
});
```

I assume it as `twitter-bootstrap modal` by looking at its code and I would prefer emptying `elements` on close of the `modal` as below

```
$('#event-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal',function(){
     //fires everytime modal is closed by any sort of event
     $('#event-modal .myTable').empty();
});
```